# Циклические функции или цикл в цикле

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток!

У меня имеется две функции **chapter** и **chapterId**.
Обе функции используют циклы для того, что бы получить все данные с обоих таблиц.
Это работает примерно так:

Первая таблица **Sc_rules_chapter** содержит в себе столбцы **id**, **title**.
Вторая таблица **Sc_rules_id** содержит столбцы **id**, **chapter**, **chapter2**, **name** и **punishment**.

Вот так выглядят функции:

```
<?php
private function chapterId($chapter = "")
{
    ob_start();
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `Sc_rules_id` WHERE `chapter` = '$chapter'");
    if (!$query || $this->db->num_rows() <= 0) {
        echo "none";
    }
    while ($arg = $this->db->fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $data = array(
            "chapter" => $arg["chapter"],
            "chapter2" => $arg["chapter2"],
            "name" => $arg["name"],
            "punish" => $arg["punishment"]
        );
        echo $this->core->loadPage("modules/rules/chapter-id", $data);
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}

private function chapter()
{
    ob_start();
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `Sc_rules_chapter`");
    if (!$query || $this->db->num_rows() <= 0) {
        echo "error";
    }
    while ($arg = $this->db->fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $data = array(
            "chapter" => $arg["chapter"],
            "name" => $arg["name"],
            "list" => $this->chapterId($arg["chapter"]),
        );
        echo $this->core->loadPage("modules/rules/chapter", $data);
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
?>
```

Когда в **$data** у функции **chapter** вставить функцию **chapterId**, работает только по одному запросу в бд, то есть он выводит только 1 результат из бд **Sc_rules_chapter**, как это исправить?

Comment: А в чем идея использования буфферизации? 
Есть вариант сделать просто `join` и собрать все одним запросом?

Comment: @AidarSaifutdinov можно и join, простыми словами, есть таблица с разделами правил и таблица с самими правилами. Нужно циклом пройтись по разделам и вторым циклом вставить в нужные разделы сами правила

Comment: Почему используется буфферизация  `ob_start()` и т.д.? Чем обусловлено?

Comment: @AidarSaifutdinov честно не знаю, так было использовано в одном из движков сайта который я разберал, и там в циклах везде использовалась буферизация, без него отображение циклов выводилось не туда куда нужно.